# Algorithm to get the 2 most distant point in a 2D plane (for homework)

Tags: algorithm, performance, points

I have to make a efficient algorithm that gets two point that are the most distant from each other and I am trying to get the O(nlogn) complexity.
I searched for an efficient algorithm, but all I could find is for the closest points.

The output should just print the 2 points.

What I found by now is this algorithm from GeeksForGeeks : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/
but is for the closest points.

And this  solution:

mukeshiiitm.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/find-the-farthest-pair-of-points/

that looks way to complicated for a homework.

First method, looks weird, plus I don't think it works for my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't know the algorithm but you want to write the code. That's not possible and it's not the correct way to write software. First make clear what you want to do. Then start writing code. This question is not about C++. It's about algorithms.

Comment: It is for my homework, I am still learning, of course I don't know the algorithm.

Comment: In that case you asked the wrong question. You asked for help with your code. But how could someone help you with your code if you can't describe what it should do in detail? Remove the C++ code and the tag. Add the tag algorithm. Describe what you've tried so far. Your question should be completely unrelated to C++. Algorithms are independent of the programming language.

Comment: I change the question as you suggested. I hope it didn't hurt anybody the fact that a newbie asked the wrong question.

Comment: Convex Hull is the keyword you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is homework so no code examples :)

Here's O(n log n) approach:

1. Find [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of all given points using any of O(n log n) convex hull algorithms
2. Now we can notice that 2 farthest points will still be on convex hull
3. We can find such points using  [Rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) technique in O(n) time